# Column headers are appearing multiple times in crosstab report

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

[image]

I have created a cross tab report in JasperReports. All I want to display complete data on single page with out repeat of Header. But currently its showing header multiple times.

Comment: Please add a picture how the report looks now and what you expect it to be.

Comment: @tobi6 i have attached screenshot.Do let me know if any thing else you required.

Comment: Thank you guys, found the solution by setting up crosstab report property repeat column headers to false.

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

set up crosstab report property repeat column headers to false and It will work. Cheers... :)